# Login on website with java

Tags: java, http, post, authentication

I would like to login to a website with java. I use the org.apache.http and I already written

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?      service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Fhl%3Dsl%26tab%3Dwm%26ui%3Dhtml%26zy%3Dl&bsv=llya694le36z&scc=1&ltmpl=default&");
try {
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vb_login_username",
                    "XXX"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vb_login_password",
                    "XXX"));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(line);
            }
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It sends the post form correctly i have tested, though i still cant login. The website I want to login is http://www.xtratime.org/forum/  Any ideas for this or is there a different way?

Comment: Why are there all those spaces after the `?` in the url?

Comment: The URL in your code does not math with the URL of your target website. Isn't that just a red herring?

Comment: What is in the HttpResponse?  Is the response code 200?  Is the returned HTML still the login page?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot change the URl to my target website. The returned html is still the login page.

Comment: Use Wireshark with filters "ip.addr == putHereIpOfServer && http" to find out what is included in your login request and how it defers when you login normally. This helped me work out my issues with logging in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<form action="login.php?do=login" method="post" 
    onsubmit="md5hash(vb_login_password, vb_login_md5password, 
        vb_login_md5password_utf, 0)">
```

- Before submit the page encode the password (`onsubmit`). You should do the same in the code.
- The value of the `action` attribute does not match with your code (`https://accounts.google.com...`). You should send the post request to the `login.php?do=login`.

And there are a lot of hidden fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="s" 
    value="b804473163cb55dce0d43f9f7c41197a" />

<input type="hidden" name="securitytoken" 
    value="0dcd78b4c1a376232b62126e7ad568e0d1213f95" />

<input type="hidden" name="do" value="login" />     

<input type="hidden" name="vb_login_md5password" />

<input type="hidden" name="vb_login_md5password_utf" />
```

You should send these parameters too.

Usually it's easier to install an [HttpFox Firefox Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/) an inspect the request for the post parameters than decoding the javascript.

My browser sends these post parameters (captured with HttpFox, the password is `pass1`):

```
vb_login_username: user1
vb_login_password:
s: 5d8bd41a83318e683de9c55a38534407
securitytoken: 0dcd78b4c1a376232b62126e7ad568e0d1213f95
do: login
vb_login_md5password: a722c63db8ec8625af6cf71cb8c2d939
vb_login_md5password_utf: a722c63db8ec8625af6cf71cb8c2d939
```

**Edit**:

The following works for me, I can get the *"Thank you for logging in"* message in the printed html code:

```
final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
        "http://www.xtratime.org/forum/login.php?do=login");
try {
    final List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = 
        new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vb_login_username",
            "my user"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vb_login_password", ""));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("s", ""));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("securitytoken",
            "inspected with httpfox, like f48d01..."));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("do", "login"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vb_login_md5password",
            "inspected with httpfox, like 8e6ae1..."));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
            "vb_login_md5password_utf",
            "inspected with httpfox, like 8e6ae1..."));

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    final HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    final BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            response.getEntity().getContent()));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (final IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Does this mean I should hash the value I set for "vb_login_password" or should send the hash as something else

Comment: I think you should. Check my updated answer. I suggest using HttpFox if you're planning to use just one password.

Comment: Check the update and post your new codes if it still not works.

Comment: The examples work ..but i dint get where to put the username and password..Would you mind to tell , where to put the username and pasword.

Comment: @DilaGurung: Username and password are encoded by the client side JavaScript `md5hash` function which puts them into post parameters. Probably it's in the `vb_login_md5password*` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/):

> HtmlUnit is a "GUI-Less browser for Java programs". It models HTML
>   documents and provides an API that allows you to invoke pages, fill
>   out forms, click links, etc... just like you do in your "normal"
>   browser.
>
> It has fairly good JavaScript support (which is constantly improving)
>   and is able to work even with quite complex AJAX libraries, simulating
>   either Firefox or Internet Explorer depending on the configuration you
>   want to use.
>
> It is typically used for testing purposes or to retrieve information
>   from web sites.

Comment: Is this feature rich, stable and active project like selenium ? Are there any strong GUI-LESS alternatives to HtmlUnit ? Thanks.

Comment: In a gui/browser based testing api, I can open only one webpage because there is only one mouse pointer in a computer to do the clicking. So, can I run multiple tests on the same website with html unit since this has no gui and presumably does not move the mouse ? Thanks.