# Login to a website (Java)

Tags: java, authentication

I want to login to a website, but if I try it with this code:
package URL;

```
//Variables to hold the URL object and its connection to that URL.
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLLogin {
    private static URL URLObj;
private static URLConnection connect;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Establish a URL and open a connection to it. Set it to output mode.
        URLObj = new URL("http://login.szn.cz");
        connect = URLObj.openConnection();
        connect.setDoOutput(true);        
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.out.println("The URL specified was unable to be parsed or uses an invalid protocol. Please try again.");
        System.exit(1); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("An exception occurred. " + ex.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }


    try {
        // Create a buffered writer to the URLConnection's output stream and write our forms parameters.
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"));
        writer.write("username=S&password=s&login=Přihlásit se");
        writer.close();

     // Now establish a buffered reader to read the URLConnection's input stream.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));

        String lineRead = "";

        Read all available lines of data from the URL and print them to screen.
        while ((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(lineRead);
        }

        reader.close();  
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("There was an error reading or writing to the URL: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

I get this error:

> There was an error reading or writing to the URL: Server returned HTTP
>   response code: 405 for URL: http://login.szn.cz

Is here a way how I can login to this website? Or maybe I can use cookies in Opera browser with login information?

Thanks for all advices.

Comment: I use HtmlUnit for such jobs because it not only supports cookies but also javascript.

Comment: The page you are trying to access is a simple HTML page - you should be using https://login.szn.cz/loginProcess instead. Also, you need to use an SSL connection. Also, you need to specify the request method as POST and the Content-Type as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. Also you need to encode the data you are writing to the request body. Also, you seem to be missing some parameters (at least compared to when you login using the main HTML page). You might want to HtmlUnit, as suggested by @MrSmith42.

Comment: You can try casting `connect` to `HttpURLConnection` and then set the request method to POST using `setRequestMethod("POST");`

Comment: @MrSmith42
I downloaded htmlUnit and it looks great. With this I'm able to login to my site and it's more elegant solution. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `URL` object's `openConnection` method to get a `URLConnection` object. You can use this `URLConnection` object to setup parameters and general request properties that you may need before connecting. Connection to the remote object represented by the `URL` is only initiated when the `URLConnection.connect` method is called. The following code opens a connection to the site *example.com*:

```
try {
    URL myURL = new URL("http://login.szn.cz");
    URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
    myURLConnection.connect();
} 
catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
    // new URL() failed
    // ...
} 
catch (IOException e) {   
    // openConnection() failed
    // ...
}
```

A new `URLConnection` object is created every time by calling the `openConnection` method of the protocol handler for this `URL`.

Also see these links..

- http://www.coderanch.com/t/524061/open-source/Java-program-Login-website-url
- [Login on website with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622011/login-on-website-with-java)

Comment: I use the advice form MrSmith42, but thanks for yours reply :)